# Store Animation State When Coming Back To URL

Tags: javascript, php, state

I have a simple JS scroll event that when an element gets to within 50px of the top of the window the header animates and changes colour, which is done by using `getBoundingClientRect().top < 50` on a trigger element. This functionality is only on the home page of the site.

Is there anyway of having it so when a user visits another URL/page on the site, and then comes back to this page via the browsers `back` arrow, that the previous animation state is still applied? If the page reloads and starts at the top again it doesn't matter, but if you click back to the page that uses this code, the menu transition happens even if you return to part of the page that was past the trigger point. I don't want to force the page to the top each time because this page is going to have downloadable and searchable info on, so that it would be real pain to be sent back to the top of that page each time.

I've given a working example below and via the CodePen link, the problem is of course on CodePen and StackOverflow when you go to a different URL and then click back to URL in question it actually reloads the page from scratch again, which doesn't happen as standard browser behaviour on day-to-day websites.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anna_paul/pen/bGvPWRj

In that back end I'm using PHP, and I do have access to this is there needs to be a server side solution.

Any ideas or suggestions appreciated.

**Note:** On the actual site this scroll event is invoked via a debounce function, but I have removed this for code simplicity.

```js
let triggerElement = document.getElementById('trigger-element'),
header = document.getElementById('h')

let menuChange = function() {
 if(triggerElement.getBoundingClientRect().top < 50) {
      header.style.background = 'black'
      header.style.transition = '1s'
  } else {
      header.style.background = 'red'
      header.style.transition = '.15s'
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', menuChange)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

#h {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#trigger-element {
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background:blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header id="h">
  <p>HEADER CONTENT</p>
</header>
<div id="trigger-element">Trigger Element</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `localStorage` for this particular use case, because it can easily be implemented alongside your current method:

```js
const triggerElement = document.getElementById('trigger-element');
const header = document.getElementById('h');

const animationTriggered = localStorage.getItem('animationTriggered') === 'true';
let initialLoad = true;

const menuChange = function() {
  if (animationTriggered && initialLoad) {
    header.style.background = 'black';
  } else if (triggerElement.getBoundingClientRect().top < 50) {
    header.style.background = 'black';
    header.style.transition = '1s';
    localStorage.setItem('animationTriggered', 'true');
  } else {
    header.style.background = 'red';
    header.style.transition = '.15s';
    localStorage.setItem('animationTriggered', 'false');
  }
  
  initialLoad = false;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', menuChange);
```

This will remember the previous state and apply the black background color if the animation was previously triggered. This adds a small amount of overhead, but in a real-world scenario it should not have any noticeable impact on the performance of the application.

Comment: thanks for this Aaron. I've had a side effect of what I'm trying to achieve, which I've posted as a separate question, do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73523391/invoke-a-debounce-function-after-a-scroll-has-happened-or-after-an-initial-delay

Comment: No problem :) and I'd be happy to take a look

Comment: If a user clicks an internal site link after the animation has been triggered, and then returns to the home page via a site link, when they first scroll the header briefly flashes into the animation state then out of it again. I think this is being caused by the state still being 'true', but the user is back at the top of the scroll (i.e before the trigger point). I tried to fix it with `if(window.pageYOffset === 0) {localStorage.setItem = 'false'}`, which does reset it `false` if the user returns via an internal site link. Weirdly the flash of animation on the header still happens though?

Comment: @Emmy the original question was about support for back button navigation, which my solution answered. While I would be happy to assist you if you have a third question that requires internal support, removing the accepted answer status due to additional information that was not requested is rather bad practice

Comment: actually yes, that's fair enough. I'll do a separate question