# Invoke A Debounce Function After A Scroll Has Happened Or After An Initial Delay - Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, debouncing

I have a menu animation that is triggered when a user scrolls a certain distance down the page, because this only happens on the home page I'm using `localStorage` to store the animation state so when a user navigates back to the home page via the browser back arrow the correct animation state is shown. This all works OK.

I have since added a standard debounce function I use on scroll events and there is a problem. The debounce is delaying the implementation of the `localStorage` animation state, and is thus defeating the point of using it. It delays the localStorage functionality being implemented by whatever amount of time I use in the debounce function e.g. 100 milliseconds.

I'm not actually sure which way to approach this is, do I need to:

a) have the debounce function only execute after the user has first physically scrolled or,

b) set some kind of initial timeout, so the debounce function won't work for at least 1 second etc after page load (this seems like a better idea?)

I've included a CodePen link and the sandbox code below, although both of the sites do a page refresh when you revisit the page via the browser back arrow so I'm not sure they'll be much use in showing the problem.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anna_paul/pen/XWELPrZ

```js
const triggerElement = document.getElementById('trigger-element');
const header = document.getElementById('h');

const animationTriggered = localStorage.getItem('animationTriggered') === 'true';
let initialLoad = true;

const menuChange = function() {
  if (animationTriggered && initialLoad) {
    header.style.background = 'black';
  } else if (triggerElement.getBoundingClientRect().top < 50) {
    header.style.background = 'black';
    header.style.transition = '1s';
    localStorage.setItem('animationTriggered', 'true');
  } else {
    header.style.background = 'red';
    header.style.transition = '.15s';
    localStorage.setItem('animationTriggered', 'false');
  }
  initialLoad = false;
}

// deBounce function
const debounce = (method, delay) => {
    clearTimeout(method._tId);
    method._tId= setTimeout(() => {
        method();
    }, delay);
}

// menuChange function invoked with a the debounce function
addEventListener('scroll', ()=> {
    debounce(menuChange, 100);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

#h {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#trigger-element {
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background:blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header id="h">
  <p>HEADER CONTENT</p>
</header>
<div id="trigger-element">Trigger Element</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to simply have a different initial `eventListener`, since you already have tracking of whether the page is initially loading, and after the initial load then transition it to your `debounce` listener:

```js
// deBounce function
const debounce = (method, delay) => {
    clearTimeout(method._tId);
    method._tId= setTimeout(() => {
        method();
    }, delay);
}

const triggerElement = document.getElementById('trigger-element');
const header = document.getElementById('h');

const animationTriggered = localStorage.getItem('animationTriggered') === 'true';
let initialLoad = true;

const menuChange = function() {
  if (initialLoad) {
    if (animationTriggered) {
      header.style.background = 'black';
    }
    
    removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFunc);
    addEventListener('scroll', scrollFunc = function() {
      // menuChange function invoked WITH the debounce function
       debounce(menuChange, 100);
    });
  } else if (triggerElement.getBoundingClientRect().top < 50) {
    header.style.background = 'black';
    header.style.transition = '1s';
    localStorage.setItem('animationTriggered', 'true');
  } else {
    header.style.background = 'red';
    header.style.transition = '.15s';
    localStorage.setItem('animationTriggered', 'false');
  }
  
  initialLoad = false;
}

// menuChange function invoked WITHOUT the debounce function
addEventListener('scroll', scrollFunc = function() {
   menuChange();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

#h {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#trigger-element {
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background:blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header id="h">
  <p>HEADER CONTENT</p>
</header>
<div id="trigger-element">Trigger Element</div>
```

This is possible by transitioning the `eventListener` from an anonymous arrow function to a named function, allowing us to call `removeEventListener` on that particular listener so a new one can replace it.

Comment: thanks Aaron. This seems to work OK. I've found a bug on the original question which I've mentioned in the comments of that question. I think I know what's causing it but can't seem to squash it.